# Return array for a field event | javascript | acrobat editor

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I am trying to return an array for a dropdown change event.
The code for custom keystroke script for a drop down is as follows:

```js
if( event.willCommit )
{
   var array = this.Page1_FieldSet(3);  
}
```

The document-level javascript is as follows:

```js
var Page1_array = {
 1: {val: 1},
 2: {val: 2},
 3: {val: 3}};

function Page1_FieldSet(i)
{
 var array = Page1_Array[i];
 return array;
}
```

I am trying to access the array Page1_Array on the change of a dropdown value in pdf form. On debugging I am getting the referencing error. Please help me with the correct code. Here's the error:

```
Error: ReferenceError: Page1_Array is not defined 15:Document-Level:Page1_FieldSet
```

Comment: Page1_array is an object and not an array, but since you are trying to lookup the element at index 8, it is going to fail as you only have 3 items in Page1_array

Comment: Please post the text of the error.

Comment: Error: ReferenceError: Page1_Array is not defined
15:Document-Level:Page1_FieldSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have scope issues...

Here you're defining `Page1_array`:

```
var Page1_array = {
```

Notice the lowercase `a` in `array`.

But here you're referencing `Page1_Array`:

```
var array = Page1_Array[i];
```

...which is a different reference because of the uppercase `A`. Just change the `A` to `a`.